# Symfony2 image optimiztion

Tags: symfony, image-optimization

I have a site developed with symfony2. It's full of images. But now problem  is, its taking too much time to load images. Is there any easy way to compress all images with single command? 
I have read this doc [link](http://symfony.com/doc/2.1/cookbook/assetic/jpeg_optimize.html) 
but it seems need to place the {% image %} tag for every images on the twig template. I dont want to do that as i have imgage tag in more than 100 files. So please suggest me an easy and good way to do that. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are these pictures from your database ? Or where ?

Comment: @GuillaumeFache - No all under file server. Mostly under businesses directory.